# Updating Activity with OnResume after Fragment Closes

Tags: android, android-fragments, onresume, dismiss

I have a fragment that adds data to my database. When I close it with *dismiss()*, it returns to my activity. I want to then update my recyclerView in that activity.

My understanding of the activity lifecycle is that onResume should be called correct? I have a Log in my onResume method and as far as I can tell it is not being called.

What is the better solution, and why is this not being called?

onResume

```
  @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e("Resume", "Resuming");

}
```

The button click listener in my fragment. The Log here works perfectly fine.

```
  //save button for saving workouts
    mButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String title = mEditText.getText().toString();
            String category = mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String weight = mEditText2.getText().toString();
            int icon = buildIcon(category);

            //pass all the data into a new object for the Recycler View to store and show also refresh
            db.addWorkout(new Workout(title, weight, "8/8/8", icon));
            Log.e("Database Build", "Added a new workout: " + title);

            dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: The activity is not paused so it doesn't enter `onResume` when the fragment is closed. This is because activities host fragments. You don't see the activity because the fragment is simply overlaid, but technically the activity is still visible as far as the OS is concerned. If you want to communicate something back to the activity you should send some type of event from the fragment and subscribe to that event in the activity. Or you could use a callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Activity was never paused when you started dealing with the fragment. `onResume` won't get called in that scenario and that's expected lifecycle behavior.

You should consider implementing some type of callback to let the Activity know when the Fragment has closed. The [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) has a really good explanation of how to communicate with fragments. Use the pattern in the documentation and build yourself an `OnFragmentClosedListener`

Comment: Perfect thank you, I had started working on doing an interface method to communicate, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't doing things the hard way if unnecessary.